# list of nodes checking in to chef server in last one hour

Tags: chef-infra

How do I list the "node names" of nodes , successfully checking in to my chef server in last one hour?

Currently I am using the following command, but how do I refine it to meet the above criteria :

```
/opt/chef/bin/knife search node
```

**EDIT1**
I also tried to use the following :

```
knife exec -E 'node.all.filter{|n| Time.now - n["ohai_time"].to_i <= 3600}.map{|n| puts n.name}' -c /opt/cap1/developer12/developer/knife.rb -VV
```

But it is failing :

```
INFO: Using configuration from /opt/cap1/developer12/developer/knife.rb 
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/shell/ext.rb:294:in `node': undefined method `session' for Shell:Module (NoMethodError) 
from -E Argument:in `run' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/exec.rb:51:in `instance_eval' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/exec.rb:51:in `run' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:417:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:416:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:213:in `run' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run' 
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>' 
from /usr/bin/knife:40:in `load' 
from /usr/bin/knife:40:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to search for all nodes (`*:*`) and then filter them on your side. You can do this with `knife exec` fairly easily.

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.all.filter{|n| Time.now - n["ohai_time"].to_i <= 3600}.map{|n| puts n.name}'
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks , I am getting the following error :
'INFO: Using configuration from /opt/cap1/developer12/developer/knife.rb
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/shell/ext.rb:294:in `node': undefined method `session' for Shell:Module (NoMethodError)
 from -E Argument:in `run'
 from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/exec.rb:51:in `instance_eval''

Comment: Sorry, that should be `nodes.all`.

Comment: It worked like this :  /opt/chefdk/bin/knife search node "ohai_time:[* TO $(date +%s -d '1 hour ago')]" -i  | grep -v grep | grep -v "items found" | grep -v '^\s*$'

Comment: That is not correct, the `TO` operator in Solr doesn't do numeric ranges because Solr is a text search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is to use [`knife status`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_status.html) which will list nodes with last run update time.

Unfortunately, knife status has an option to filter healthy nodes (checked in within last hour) but not to filter unhealthy ones so you have to filter the output with something:

```
knife status | awk -F',' 'BEGIN {cmd="date +\"%s\""; cmd | getline sdate; close(cmd)} {cmd="date -d \""$1"\" +\"%s\"";cmd | getline rdate; close(cmd); if ((sdate - rdate) <= 3600) print $2}'
```

Awk script detailled:

- `BEGIN {cmd="date +\"%s\""; cmd | getline sdate; close(cmd)}` store the actual date in `sdate` variable
- `{cmd="date -d \""$1"\" +\"%s\"";cmd | getline rdate; close(cmd);` store the run date in `rdate`
- `if ((sdate - rdate) <= 3600) print $2}` if difference under 1 hour, print the node name.

That said @coderanger answer is easiest to adapt to print other informations from the node.

Comment: It worked like this :  /opt/chefdk/bin/knife search node "ohai_time:[* TO $(date +%s -d '1 hour ago')]" -i  | grep -v grep | grep -v "items found" | grep -v '^\s*$'

Comment: @IshuGupta Why are you using `grep -v grep` there ? Unless you wish to avoid nodes named grep. That said, you can add your own answer, it's perhaps the better solution, taking advantage of solr indexing to filter the search. (But I'm pretty sure you can  just `grep -v '(^\s*$|items found)'` instead of those 3 piped greps.

Comment: You are correct , I was testing something and it remained there while pasting. Thanks

Comment: Again, you're absolutely allowed to answer yourself on SO and accept it. And honestly your solution sounds the best one as it does the filter on server side (I assume @coderanger answer does on client side on the results but I may be wrong).